# Limit of a sequence involving partial sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've encountered the following curious sequence. I think the limit is correct from simulations, but I'm getting stuck on how to prove it. Any hints?

Fix $\gamma \in (0,1)$. Then:
$$\sum_{i=n \gamma}^n \frac{n}{i^2} \; \to \; \frac{1-\gamma}{\gamma} \quad \textrm{ as } n \to \infty$$

**EDIT:** I'm not sure it matters, but for now take $n \gamma$ to mean "the ceiling of $n \gamma$."

Comment: Can you explain what does $$\sum_{i=n \gamma}^n \frac{n}{i^2}$$ mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define new index variable $x$ as $\frac{i}{n}$, so that an index increment of $1$ for index $i$ maps to an index increment of $\Delta x=\frac{1}{n}$.

Now, as $n\to \infty$ (i.e. $\Delta x\to 0$) the summation will tend towards the definite integral, 
$$\sum_{i=n \gamma}^n \frac{n}{i^2} =\sum_{x=\gamma}^1 \frac{1}{nx^2}=\sum_{x=\gamma}^1 \frac{\Delta x}{x^2} \to \int_\gamma^1\frac{dx}{x^2}=\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_\gamma^1=\frac{1-\gamma}{\gamma}  \quad \textrm{ as } \Delta x \to 0$$